# Why is java.util.Date mutable in java?

Tags: java

As I was returning the actual reference of `Date` object in a getter of a class. But SonarQube didn't accepted it a good practice. And then I found that returning references to internal mutable members of a class can compromise an application's security, both by breaking encapsulation and by providing the opportunity to corrupt the internal state of the class (whether accidentally or maliciously). 
Now I'm thinking: Why is `java.util.Date` mutable in java ?

Comment: Because of a design oversight 20 years back.

Comment: And if you use Java 8, there are suitable immutable classes in the `java.time` package.

Comment: @TheLostMind It's not a defensive copy of a mutable object. It returns an immutable object.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Ya, that makes sense. My bad. Thanks :)